# GWT widgets are showed without a style

Tags: gwt

I try the TabPanel and the PopUp widget but both are showed in the browser without a style... other examples that I've downloaded from the internet are fine. What's going on?

That's an example of what I see... What I missing?
Thanks

[image]

That's my code:

```
.....
        Button search = Button.wrap(DOM.getElementById("search"));
        search.setVisible(true);

        search.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                new MyPopup().show();
            }           
        });

    }

      private static class MyPopup extends PopupPanel {

            public MyPopup() {
              // PopupPanel's constructor takes 'auto-hide' as its boolean parameter.
              // If this is set, the panel closes itself automatically when the user
              // clicks outside of it.
              super(true);

              // PopupPanel is a SimplePanel, so you have to set it's widget property to
              // whatever you want its contents to be.
              setWidget(new Label("Click outside of this popup to close it"));
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your theme set to in your .gwt.xml file?  I would assume your default GWT style sheet isn't chosen.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html

Example, mine is the un-commented Chrome one as an example :

```
  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <!--<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>-->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/>
```

Past that I would say "inspect the element" on chrome or use the built in browser developer tools to see what CSS file is being loaded or applied.